# Warning: QNetworkDiskCache::prepare() unable to open temporary file

Tags: qgis, wms, cache

When I run qgis 1.8.0 on Linux and load a WMS layer from a remote server
I get messages (in terminal) saying

Warning: QNetworkDiskCache::prepare() unable to open temporary file

Downloading tiles from the WMS server was quite slow. So I wondered if
having a tile cache would help.

Is there some configuration variable I can set so that the QNetworkDiskCache
can open a temporary file? e.g. by specifying a location for temporary files?

Or can this warning safely be ignored?

Thanks, David

Answer (score 1):

this answer is late but anyway... I just hit the same issue here. I don't know why but QGIS lost the ability to write in its default tmp folder (see options -> network) and it was just enough to change it.