# setDataSource on WFS layer crash QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, wfs

When I try to change with python the datasource of a WFS layer, QGis crashes with this error:

Warning: QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::raiseError( QString ) to QgsVectorLayer::raiseError( QString )

My code is:

```
        ...
        newDatasource = urllib.quote_plus(wfsURI)
        WFSLayer.setDataSource(newDatasource, wfs_layer_name, "wfs", True)
        WFSLayer.reload()
```

where WFSLayer is a qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

My solution: i delete the old features and add new ones from temporary layer.

```
# delete existing features
idF = []
for f in WFSLayer.getFeatures():
    idF.append(f.id())
WFSLayer.startEditing()
for idFea in idF:
    WFSLayer.deleteFeature(idFea)
WFSLayer.commitChanges()

# new temporary layer
v_layerNew = QgsVectorLayer(uri, wfs_layer_name, "WFS")

# add new features to old layer
WFSLayer.startEditing()
for feature in v_layerNew.getFeatures():
    WFSLayer.addFeature(feature)                        
WFSLayer.commitChanges()
```

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the wrong parameter "wfs" in "WFS" (uppercase), and
i applied this solution to the write cache Qgis bug:
[Warning: QNetworkDiskCache::prepare() unable to open temporary file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42491/warning-qnetworkdiskcacheprepare-unable-to-open-temporary-file)

Now it has disappeared the above error, but it presents a new one:

```
segmentation error
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to removing the layer by code and setting a new WFS vector layer like this:

```
# first instance of WFSlayer
url1 = "http://myServer.com/geoserver/wfs?version=1.0.0&service=wfs&typeName=StoreName:layerName1&request=GetFeature"
WFSlayer = QgsVectorLayer(url1, "layer1", "WFS")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(WFSlayer)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayers( [WFSlayer.id()] )

# second instance of WFSlayer
url2 = "http://myServer.com/geoserver/wfs?version=1.0.0&service=wfs&typeName=StoreName:layerName2&request=GetFeature"
WFSlayer = QgsVectorLayer(url2, "layer2", "WFS")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(WFSlayer)
```

Comment: I don't want to add a new layer, otherwise i loose the settings of the existing level.